# Why was the analyse immortal draw question deleted an hour ago?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, re-open, deleted-questions

[How do I analyse immortal draw?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41461/how-do-i-analyse-immortal-draw)

---

I really don't get this game at all. 1 day I just heard about it. I plugged it into lichess. But apparently lichess analysis is getting it wrong. It says move X is a blunder when actually it isn't at all.

I asked about why engines were confused by this

[Why can't immortal draw be analysed?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41455/why-cant-immortal-draw-be-analysed)

and also how to analyse it but then it was closed for too broad so I made a new post and then now it's deleted [How do I analyse immortal draw?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41461/how-do-i-analyse-immortal-draw) with no explanation in comments.

Answer (score 8):

You posted an almost exact duplicate of a previously closed question of yours. Of course it was deleted.